# how can I make or change a manifest in java?

Tags: java, manifest

I wanna add Extension-List to **manifest**. but I don't know that how make manifest file for java project? or where can I find it, if it was made before?

I've read [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/extensions.html#manifest) but I didn't find a good content for making or changing a manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below command to create manifest file :

```
 jar cfm <jar-file> <manifest-addition>
```

refer the link [java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) for more info